# When is the product a compound and when is it 2 ions in these reactions?

Tags: redox

When finding the half equation and overall redox equation for the following:

a) $\ce{Fe^2+(aq) + Cl2(g) <=>}$
b) $\ce{N2(g) + H2(g)  <=>}$

The solution from the textbook is given below. I do not understand why the products (in the overall reaction) for **a)** are 2 individual ions (and not **$\ce{FeCl3}$** whilst the product for **b)** is a compound (and not **$\ce{2N3- + 6H+}$**).

One difference I noted was, when the electrons are balanced for **a)** it gives **$\ce{2Fe3+}$** and **$\ce{2Cl-}$** , which cannot go together unless its **$\ce{2Fe3+}$** and **$\ce{6Cl-}$**, whilst for **b)**, when the electrons are balanced we have **$\ce{6H+}$** and **$\ce{N2}$** which combine as is to form **$\ce{2NH3}$**. Is this the reason?

The solution given is:

a)
Oxidation: $\ce{2Fe^2+(s) -> 2Fe^3+ + 2e- }$
Reduction: $\ce{Cl2(g) + 2e- -> 2Cl- }$
Overall: $\ce{2Fe^2+ (aq) + Cl2(g) <=> 2Fe^3+ + 2Cl- }$

b)
Oxidation: $\ce{3H2 -> 6H+ + 6e-}$
Reduction: $\ce{N2 + 6e-  -> 2N^3-}$
Overall: $\ce{N2(g) + 3H2(g)  <=> 2NH3}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While FeCl3 is a possible product, the reaction in A is aqueous. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_chloride) shows that is readily dissolves in water (92 g/100 mL @ 20C). The products exist as ions, and are written as such.

I would suspect you're not supposed to have solubility constants memorized though, so in general if it is in water they will exist as ions.

B is a gaseous reaction and the product is a compound, not an ion set like A.